# What's the actual likeability of "voice control"?

Tags: psychology, google-glass, voice-browser

I recently got to design an app for Google Glass, and I was wondering: how much users really like that they have to speak out loud to have control over the device or to undertake an action? Are there any tests that shows how much confortable the average user is with the voice control, how much does he likes/hates it?

I crave tests! Can be anything: neuroscientific tests, psychology tests, focus groups.. whatever has shown some indication in one way or another.

Comment: I think you also have to account for differences between individual users.  Some people (and maybe more than just the developers) obviously like them.  At the other extreme, there are people like me who would never use one.

Comment: Good question.  I personally loath the attempts with call centre software to attempt to understand speach and would much rather just listen to some options and press the right number.

Comment: Voice alone won't do it. Voice with gestures should cover about 99% of what a typical user wants to do. (People love to point.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great summary of why VUIs will never entirely win the day:

> [I]t's not that voice is useless. It's just that it is often a
>   secondary interaction mode when additional media are available. It's
>   much easier to pick out the desired item from a list when the list is
>   displayed on a monitor than when it's read aloud. Voice is a
>   one-dimensional medium with zero persistence; a monitor is a
>   two-dimensional medium that combines persistence (you can look at it
>   for as long as you please) with selective updating (you can type a
>   value into a field anywhere on the screen without changing the rest of
>   the screen).

While the source is reputable and research-focused, [the article itself](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/voice-interfaces-assessing-the-potential/)  does not reference any specific research.

Answer (score 1):

I havent found any articles or research which shows whether users **like** it or **hate** it but studies have shown that voice alone can be a frustrating experience at times due to the lack of clarity and affirmation of the task being asked. To quote this [article](http://www.usertesting.com/blog/2015/04/28/voice-command-siri-google-now-cortana/)

> **Our research** To answer these questions, we ran a simple user experience study on popular smartphone personal assistants Siri,
>   Google Now, and Cortana.
>
> We asked nine participants (three using each system) to set up dinner
>   and a movie with a friend using their voice as much as possible.
>
> The tasks started off simple: looking up the evening’s weather and (if
>   it was going to be cold) instructions on how to tie a scarf.

With regards to the task being a success,

> **Step 1: “What’s the weather going to be like tonight?”**
>
> The stereotypical use case for voice commands, asking for the
>   evening’s weather was natural and simple. Even though participants
>   chose different commands ranging from the abrupt “Weather” to the more
>   personal “Is it going to be cold?”, all of their devices presented
>   them with a well-formatted display of the day’s weather forecast, even
>   reading the forecast aloud in some cases.

However it always didnt go well

> Asking for instructions on how to tie a scarf did not provide the same
>   immediate satisfaction, showing only the results from a web search.
>   While the results were relevant to the question, the answers were
>   still a tap away.
>
> All participants found they were unable to ask multiple questions in
>   single command. While the solution was simply to split their question
>   up, the extra step disrupted the fluidity of the interaction.

Similarly there were other issues as well to quote the article

> Moving on to the brunt of the dinner and movie plan, participants
>   encountered a variety of obstacles in moving from one part of the plan
>   to the next.
>
> The process began by asking their device for “movie times” or to “take
>   me to a movie.” Much like the weather, participants received a
>   well-formatted display of local movies and showtimes. **However, getting
>   more specific required manual selection or another search, which
>   proved to be difficult to do through voice alone.**
>
> Having selected a theater, participants moved on to find a restaurant
>   near the theater. While it was easy for users to find a restaurant
>   near their current location, **it was more difficult to find a
>   restaurant near a different location or landmark.**

Other issues that came up were while trying to deal with unique names which are not normally found in the dictionary

> **Texting friends**
>   Once the participants had set up the plan for their night, the final step was to send the details to a friend. Most
>   participants found this easy, asking their device to “text [name]” or
>   “send a message to [name]”, which brought up a message dialog
>   prompting them to speak their message aloud. Many were used to doing
>   this, but still encountered frustration in cases where the systems
>   balked at uncommon names or cut off long sentences while they were
>   being spoken. Repairing these misunderstood messages involved too much
>   repetition and back-and-forth for some participants, who had negative
>   experiences and commented that they would rather just send a text
>   message manually.

---

Though the above user study is not definitive , here are some suggestions.

1. Provide alternative input information methods which allow the user to edit the request
2. Be aware of the constraints faced in places with a lot of noise or unique cases such as being able to text  a friend with a unique name
3. Allow users to break down their tasks into simpler activities which can drive greater clarity

Here are some links worth reading

[The effect of ‘Digital Assistants’ on UX and UI](http://blog.usabilla.com/effect-digital-assistants-ux-ui/)

[Speaking in Context: Designing Voice Interfaces](http://punchcut.com/perspectives/speaking-context-designing-voice-interfaces/)

[Teens Embrace Voice Search, Many Adults Feel “Like Geeks” Using It](http://searchengineland.com/teens-unihibited-voice-search-many-adults-feel-embarrassed-205881)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have tests for you but in the meanwhile let me start with this based on my gut feeling:

1) if your app for google glass supports or extends actions that are about on-the-go, contextual. I feel this it will provide a good user experience.

2) Average user might not be comfortable with the voice control / searches when sharing sensitive information (healthcare, security info, FB comments). Conflict is sharing private information in a public setting. (My hunch).

3) Voice interactions in general, I feel are NOT suited for "significant interaction". They are best used for micro interactions and then followed by other form of input like typing. If the commands are smaller and natural that helps.

if you can explain little more about your app (context and intents of voice control) that might help to answer more specific.